# Insert file into mysql Blob

Tags: mysql

I try to insert a Open Office document on a blob field.
To do this I try

```
INSERT INTO my_table (stamp, docFile) VALUES (NOW(), LOAD_FILE('/tmp/my_file.odt'));
```

This works well on windows but on Mac Os the file isn't load on docFile field.

Is anyone has experience about that?

Thanks

Comment: Try what is suggested [in this similar question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/load-file-doesnt-work

Comment: As I've done all you suggest, it's why I post. Thanks. If I use tools like phpmyAdmin or Navicate to do the same task, all work well.

Comment: Do you get any error message, check if u have permission to upload file from that directory

Comment: I check permission, and all it's good. I use zend and I did 2 tests. The first I place folder and file on webroot, no result, second I place folder and while on mysql root : same result, none. And if I do the same with phpMyAdmin the file is loaded on mysql.

Comment: Are you using a remote mysql server? The file has to be on the server, not the client.

Answer (score 1):

`File.separator` is either `/` or `\` that is used to split up the path to a specific file. For example on Windows it is `\` or `C:\Documents\Test`. But on Mac it is `/`.

So use `File.separator` instead of `/` or `\`, then it will work for both Mac and Windows.

You can Update the column value having type 'blob'

```
UPDATE `TableName` SET `ColumnName`=LOAD_FILE('FilePath/FileName.bin') WHERE `YourCondition` 
// FilePath -> C:/foldername/filename.bin
```

Comment: It doesn't work: **0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0**