# Is it possible to load BLOB into MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, blob, load-data-infile

I have tried terminating fields / lines using some long strings, but every time some entries are corrupted.
The BLOB is `numpy.array` of integers saved as `uint32` (`numpy.array(intlist, dtype='uint32').tostring()`).
Upon unload (`numpy.fromstring(blob, dtype='uint32')`), numpy reports `string size must be a multiple of element size` error.

```
mysql -p somedb -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/tmpBZRvWK' INTO TABLE `hash2protids` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '....|....' LINES TERMINATED BY '....|....\n'"
```

**EDIT**
I've tried `INSERT INTO hash2protids (hash, protids) VALUES ('key', LOAD_FILE('/tmp/tmpfile'));` ([Insert file into mysql Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109112/insert-file-into-mysql-blob)), but LOAD_FILE works only with files on the server. In addition, I have 3M rows to insert, so it's way too slow...

**EDIT2**
For now I'm relying on `MySQLdb` executemany, as it's:

- much faster than inserting single rows
- can load any datatype

Code looks something like this:

```
step = 1000
data = []
cmd = "INSERT INTO sometable (hash, protids) VALUES (%s, %s)"
for (hash, protids) in GENERATOR:
    pblob = numpy.array(protids, dtype='uint32').tostring()
    data.append((hash, pblob))
    if len(data)>step:
        cur.executemany(cmd, data)
        data = []
if data:
    cur.executemany(cmd, data)
```

Note, I've split cur.executemany every 1000 elements, as I was running into MySQL errors due to 'max_allowed_packet' limit, when all entries were executed at once.