# Problem adding an image to database using SQL

Tags: mariadb, mysql-loadfile

```
INSERT INTO items (id,name,image,price) VALUES('1','iphone 5s',LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\project\1.jpg'),300);
```

**this statement cause error**

```
INSERT INTO items (id,name,image,price) VALUES('1','iphone 5s',LOAD_FILE('C:\xampp\htdocs\project\1.jpg'),300)
MySQL said: Documentation
```

**here is the error**

```
#1048 - Column 'image' cannot be null
```

Comment: Pick a single database engine - the code required will be specific to that engine. SQL Server has no load_file function.

Comment: i used maria db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LOAD\_FILE is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8229951/608639), [How do I use LOAD_FILE to insert value from a file into a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14892219/608639), [LOAD_FILE returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18721317/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the file path of your "1.jpg" or maybe look at the image format whether it is .jpg or .png.

Else, try this format:

> LOAD_FILE('../1.jpg')

"Different backslash position"

I do not think you should mention the C:/xampp/htdocs/project because you are already in the project folder when you run your code.

Hopefully it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape backslashes in any string:

```
... LOAD_FILE('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\1.jpg') ...
```

Or, since MySQL will 'correctly' interpret forward-slashes, even on Windows:

```
... LOAD_FILE('C:/xampp/htdocs/project/1.jpg') ...
```

(I assume `image` is declared `BLOB` or `MEDIUMBLOB`?)