# Inserting image into BLOB column MySQL

Tags: mysql, blob

Not sure what's causing it, but I am unable to insert images into my BLOB/LONGBLOB column in MySQL.

I'm using the correct syntax:

```
update gift 
set gift_picture = LOAD_FILE('/Users/omarebrahim/Pictures/randoms/shoe3.jpg') 
where gift_id = 1;
```

I'm getting `0 rows affected, Rows matched: 1, Changed: 0, Warnings: 0`.

The column is a LONGBLOB and the table storage engine is MyISAM.

Comment: Has the image changed from the row's previous `gift_picture` column contents when doing the `UPDATE`?

Comment: check your access rights, chmod, chown, FILE GRANT... (why load file? why not just store the path)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load\_File doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/load-file-doesnt-work)

Comment: The column is empty, so trying to upload an image to it. Also, I'm choosing LOAD_FILE over path storage as I'm developing a website on OS X and Windows, and I'd have to keep changing the paths every time.

Comment: Nope not a duplicate, I hadn't seen the post in your link

Comment: How do I check the access rights?