# unable to insert the image in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert the  image in MySQL whenever i tried to add the image it showed null value. Pls help me to add the image. I've give the correct path but still error has occurred

```
create table image3(id int, image longblob not null);

insert into image3(id,image)values(571185, load_file('D:\Images\3.jpg'));
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Try reversing the slashes.

Comment: The error is: Error Code: 1048. Column 'img' cannot be null

Answer (score -2):

The function [`load_file()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) returns the string representation of the file (it only works with text files).

What you're trying to do is insert binary data.

**EDIT** I was wrong, disregard the answer, instead look at this one: [Load_File doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8229951/1249938)

**EDIT 2** Could it be that you have to use `/` instead of `\`? I know windows uses `\` for path separators, but it's quite frankly the only OS to do so. Therefore I can imagine that MySQL (being multiplatform) uses "the correct separators".

Comment: I doubt that. The docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) give an example with an image.

Comment: My bad, withdrawing answer