# Unable to upload image file in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I used the following code for uploading an image file into my database from an answer in stack overflow, but it is not getting updated. Please help.

```
mysql> update S516 set photo = LOAD_FILE('/home/rsreekumar/db/java16/photos/13134.PNG') where roll_no = "AM.EN.U4CSE13134";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

My question is same. but not working.

Comment: Which answer? what have you tried? What exactly is being expected that is not occuring?

Comment: is your photo column a `BLOB`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load\_File doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/load-file-doesnt-work)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8230197/3536236) to may well help you

Comment: I tried this answer but of no use.

Comment: check the file privileges SELECT user, file_priv FROM mysql.user

Comment: I am denied to access the user table.

Comment: If you can't access the user table then that really suggests your issue is you don't have permission to use `LOADFILE`. Take it up with your database provider....

Comment: yes Take it up with your database provider @SreekumarR

Answer (score 0):

Can you check?

1. mysql user has permissions to read file
2. where condition is correct
3. column photo is blob
4. you have permissions to use LOAD_FILE
5. file size less than max_allowed_packet bytes
6. if the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory
7. is AppArmor protection running (and blocking)?

Comment: `WHERE` is correct as MySQL statement returns `Rows Martched : 1`

Comment: All the privileges are there. Hope it includes reading file. Where condition is correct. Column photo is blob. I don't know how to check the permission to use LOAD_FILE. Please help

Comment: Is permission for LOAD_FILE different from ALL privileges.

Comment: Point 1 is "can /home/rsreekumar/db/java16/photos/13134.PNG be readed by user that executes query?"
that is a bit different from
"can user execute LOAD_FILE function?"

Comment: file exists and is not empty?

Comment: File exists. It is in users home directory so readable. Also, asked admin to grant file_priv which she set to 'y'. Still no use.

Comment: does 
`SELECT LOAD_FILE('/home/rsreekumar/db/java16/photos/13134.PNG');` 
return anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115393/discussion-between-diego-betto-and-sreekumar-r).