# Insert into mysql using LOAD_FILE insert null for the field

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

[image]I have the following code written in python, id is an auto increment field and the data type for sample is nvarchar(45). I want to insert the content of the file into my table; the data is unstructured:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "Mydatabases#0", "myblog")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into mytable (id,sample) values (DEFAULT ,LOAD_FILE('C:/Discharge_Summary/sample_648.txt'))")
db.commit()
db.close()
```

I do not see any error, but when I select * from my table, I see null for sample field!!! why it cannot load the file content into MySql?

The screenshot shows that I have all required permissions...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load\_File doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/load-file-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Moob thank you, I have attached a screen shot of MySql account setting, showing that I have the required permission, also, the text files are within the same machine that MySql is running, what are other possibilities that leads to having null input in MySql?