# MySQL not retrieve data in xml file using load_file command

Tags: mysql, xml, linux, database-connection

While I run this procedure I won't get any data inside the MySQL table. I'm using Linux mint OS, is there any configuration I want to add or else any mistake I made in query.

```
delimiter //
create procedure looping()
BEGIN
declare xmlset_blog longtext;
declare rowcount_blog int;
declare rowindex_blog int;
SET xmlset_blog = LOAD_FILE("/root/file/blog.xml"); 
set rowcount_blog  = extractValue(xmlset_blog 
,concat('count(','//entry',')'));
set rowindex_blog=1;
while rowindex_blog<= rowcount_blog do
insert into blog_temp (blog_id, title, authorname, published, updated, 
last_modified)values(
extractValue(xmlset_blog , 
concat('/feed/entry[',rowindex_blog,']/id')),
extractValue(xmlset_blog , 
concat('/feed/entry[',rowindex_blog,']/title')),
extractValue(xmlset_blog , 
concat('/feed/entry[',rowindex_blog,']/author/name')),
extractValue(xmlset_blog , 
concat('/feed/entry[',rowindex_blog,']/published')),
extractValue(xmlset_blog , 
concat('/feed/entry[',rowindex_blog,']/updated')),now()
);
set rowindex_blog = rowindex_blog + 1;
end while;
end //
```

Procedure gets executed there is no error displayed in code and file also available in the respective directory.

Provide me solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LOAD\_FILE to load a file into a MySQL blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/how-to-use-load-file-to-load-a-file-into-a-mysql-blob)

Comment: I provided all the permission, still i didn't get any data

Comment: Are you sure your mysql daemon runs as root (it doesn't on any of the systems I've had access to over the last couple of years)? I'd personally try a different directory (not under root's home).

Comment: this is my file directory /home/nethaji/Desktop/Nethaji/file/blog.xml

Comment: mysql user is root

Comment: I get the same result