# LOAD_FUNCTION in MySQL shows an invalid identifier

Tags: mysql

I created a table namely pictures to insert images into the table. After using the insert command and load my picture with load_function it's showing an invalid identifier.

```
CREATE table pics(id number(10),pics1 blob);

INSERT INTO pics 
values(1,LOAD_FUNCTION('C:\Users\Vandana\Desktop\face\my_image.jpg'));
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation for the existance of a `LOAD_FUNCTION` in MySQL. Please clarify

Comment: Do you mean [`LOAD_FILE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/how-to-use-load-file-to-load-a-file-into-a-mysql-blob)?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

`number` is not a valid MySQL column data type, you should use `INTEGER(10) SIGNED` [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html).

```
CREATE TABLE pics(id INTEGER(10) SIGNED, pics1 BLOB);
```

However [`NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289) is a valid data type for Oracle Database, which is very much so different from MySQL.

`LOAD_FUNCTION` is not a valid MySQL function [[sic]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/func-op-summary-ref.html).

I believe you are wanting [`LOAD_FILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file), which will retrieve the file's contents for the blob column.

You should also use double backslashes when referencing Windows file paths, to avoid escape sequence characters like `\n`.

```
INSERT INTO pics(id, pics1) 
VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('C:\\Users\\Vandana\\Desktop\\face\\my_image.jpg'));
```

> Please keep in mind that `LOAD_FILE` only has access to the files
>   located on the system and that the user/group running the database service has read permissions for.
>   See [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL is better to use **LOAD_FILE** command:

MySQL LOAD_FILE() reads the file and returns the file contents as a string, which in your case will be a *blob*

```sql
CREATE table pics(id number(10),pics1 blob); 

INSERT INTO pics 
values(1, LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\Vandana\Desktop\face\my_image.jpg'));
```

> Remembering: You need the right read privileges on your file.

You can refer: 
[More complete answer with load_file()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/how-to-use-load-file-to-load-a-file-into-a-mysql-blob)