# How to download BLOB .docx file from MySQL using python?

Tags: python, mysql

**Current Code:**

```
import mysql.connector
import sys

def write_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)

sampleNum = 0;
# select photo column of a specific author
# read database configuration
db_config = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='test',
                      host='localhost',
                      database='technical')
# query blob data form the authors table
cursor = db_config.cursor()

try:
    sampleNum=sampleNum+1;
    query = "SELECT file FROM test WHERE id=%s"
    cursor.execute(query,(sampleNum,))
    photo = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    write_file(photo, 'User'+str(sampleNum)+'.jpg')

except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

**Goal of above code**

Code above allows me to get the image from MySQL that is stored as a `BLOB` and save it into a folder where `.py` script is saved.

It works fine!

**Similar code with .docx**

```
import mysql.connector
import sys

def write_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)

sampleNum = 0;
db_config = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='test',
                      host='localhost',
                      database='technical')
cursor = db_config.cursor()

try:
    sampleNum=sampleNum+1;
    query = "SELECT fileAttachment FROM document_control WHERE id=%s"
    cursor.execute(query,(sampleNum,))
    file = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    write_file(file, 'User'+str(sampleNum)+'.docx')

except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

Here I am trying to extract and save a docx file from MySQL stored as a `BLOB` and it does not work.

The output of above script is the following:

```
    f.write(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can I extract the .docx file from MySQL?

Comment: What does `type(file)` give with `.docx`? Also can you please post some initial characters of variable `file` in the second script

Comment: Got it - here it is: `C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/Weekly Checks.xlsx`

Comment: Are you using `blob` to save the file in the database or are you just saving the path to the file?

Comment: Just as blob - We need to use blob.. cannot be using file paths. This is the query from MySQL: `insert into document_control (fileattachment) values ('C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/Weekly Checks.xlsx');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the insert query you mentioned

```
insert into document_control (fileattachment) values ('C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/Weekly Checks.xlsx');
```

it seems that you are just inserting the filepath in the database.

You must use [LOAD_FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) to insert the actual file in the database blob object.
[How to use LOAD_FILE to load a file into a MySQL blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/how-to-use-load-file-to-load-a-file-into-a-mysql-blob)

Comment: I have saved the file on MySQL server path - now it works!